# Why when click on download link there are continuation packets when the save dialog is open (before click on start save)

Tags: networking, tcp

my machine is Ubuntu.
When i click on some download link i see continuation packets, why is that ? why there are continuation packets before i start download the file

Comment: I see that i get downvote, can someone help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by fluent? Are you talking about the continuation packets? Your browser sends those to keep the connection to the web server from timing out before you decide what to do with the Save window. If those packets were not sent, then the web server might give up waiting before you had a chance to tell your browser what to do with the file.

Comment: Yep , i am talking about the continuation packets. Why is it so much packets the wireshark on my comp stuck when try captured them. i listen to nfqueue and i lose a lot of packet because this is huge amount.

Comment: When you select a large file for download you get a corresponding large number of packets.  You will get slightly less than one packet for every 1kb of file size.  On a high speed line packet capture software may not be able to keep up.

Comment: Bill, i am not talking about the download. i am asking about phase before download. when the ope/save dialog open and you still didnt chose anything. In this phase i am getting fluent of tcp packets. see the wireshark that attached.